# Prevent site marked for deletion being deleted? (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint

Basically how do I manage the task mentioned in the Title?

Problem is: I am trying to administrate a SharePoint Portal (MOSS) and a user has been deleted (deactivated from AD)

Now we got an e-mail stating that "My Site" for this user is marked for deletion (I don't know when) and since there's critical information in that site (a subsite) I would like to stop the deletion process or at least move the subsite WITHOUT losing any versioning information - is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to move the site including versions (take a GOOD look at the options in export/import using stsadm). Initially I moved the site, but got 2 aditional (unwanted) versions added. After a few trials I managed to get only the original versions moved to the new site, off the personal site from which the data originated.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288044.aspx) is some information on automatic site deletion.

Comment: Thx, that helped somewhat. Did move the site correctly though ánd it seems like I prevented the deletion also